# How to properly redirect all files inside directory with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have basically two questions.

1. How do I redirect `domain.com/ipc/` to `domain.com/category/indexpage/`? Also, what happens to `http` or `https` version and `www` or `non www` version? Are they all redirected without any problem?
2. Let's say I want to also redirect `domain.com/ipc/page` to `domain.com/category/indexpage/page`? I mean are all webpages inside the directory redirected properly? Is it also possible with `.htaccess` redirection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mod_alias` for a simple redirect inside your .htaccess file.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ipc/(.*)$ /category/indexpage/$1
```

Also this has no baring on whether it was called with http(s) or www/non www. It just handles the redirect regardless.

Comment: Will it also make sure that all files inside the directory are properly redirected?

Comment: Yes, that is what the `(.*)` is for. so it captures the value and adds it to the end. Just try it.